How to change the highlight color for PySide6 class names in PyCharm?
In PyCharm's Settings > Editor > Color Scheme there doesn't seem to be any way to change the color of PySide6 class names. They all come up as black.
I tried settings under Language Defaults > Classes > Class name, but that doesn't get applied to PySide class names, probably because they're in a library, not part of Python itself.

Anyone?

Can you show a screenshot, and the code shown in it as a snippet. In my pycharm all class names are shown in the same colour, whether built-in python classes, or classes from outside libraries.

Please don't put the screenshot in the comments, [edit] the question.

Done. My apologies for the misplaced image. I didn't realize that was a rule.

A reference to a class is not the same as the class name in the definition. It looks like pycharm doesn't have a special category for those references. You can change Color Scheme > General > Text > Default text. A lot of other elements inherit their colour from that, so you would have to change those back one by one.

Okay, thanks. I'll stick with VS Code until this gets some attention from the devs.
